# Angular 4: Module not found error regarding RxJs

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactivex

when building the Angular app I get many of these errors, below is just the first one

```
ERROR in ./~/@reactivex/rxjs/dist/cjs/Rx.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './add/operator/filter' in 
'...\node_modules\@reactivex\rxjs\dist\cjs'
 @ ./~/@reactivex/rxjs/dist/cjs/Rx.js 70:0-32
 @ ./~/@reactivex/rxjs/index.js
 @ ./~/ri-api-client/dist/index.js
 @ ./src/app/core/api.service.ts
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your error message it seems that your import statement is not correct. It complains about not finding things in node_modules/@reactivex, but it should be looking in node_modules/rxjs.

Your import statement should look like this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
```

Comment: All of my import statements are like this. I just checked the @reactivex folder and the @reactivex\rxjs\dist\cjs\add folder inside it is empty, I guess that's why it's complaining. How can I reinstall these?

Comment: Everything is there under the rxjs folder by the way

Comment: Delete you node_modules directory. Make sure that your package.json has this dependency:     "rxjs": "^5.1.0". Then run npm install again.

Comment: This answer shows the new import format for `rxjs` https://stackoverflow.com/a/52630985/8160553

Answer (score 32):

I had similar error..

```
`ERROR in ./src/app/shared/giphy/giphy.service.ts`
```

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/add/operator/map' in '/Users/user1/opt/work/mine/development/ic/ic-pms/pms-ui/src/app/shared/giphy'`
`ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
ERROR in src/app/shared/giphy/giphy.service.ts(16,35): error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'.`

Ans solution for that is
`npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save`

Comment: you saved my day!

Comment: after doing `npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save` I now get this error:
`./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/index.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open `

Comment: i wake up and try to start my project and i see error, after see your answer i install `rxjs-compat` and it fixed. i don't know why?!  :))

Answer (score 8):

RXJS changed their syntax in version 6+

The new solution should be:

`import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';`

not

`import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';`

More details here: 
https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/

Answer (score 2):

Use pipe method for `.map`
just add --

.pipe(
your code, 
map......);

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

.pipe(map(
      (response) => response.json()
 ))
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found that angular is looking for rxjs/add/operator/map in the folder where it is used in the service instead of from node_modules.

*I fixed this issue by just importing the rxjs in my app.module.ts.* Try by adding the following code in app.module.ts

```
import 'rxjs';
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need install 'rxjs-compat' if you use angular 4+.